# Where/how to unregister broadcast receiver in listview adapter?

Tags: java, android

I'm getting "Activity has leaked IntentReceiver...Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?" at runtime when executing the code below. I guess that I need to call unregisterReceiver for the Broadcast Receiver created in my_custom_adapter, but I don't know where to place the unregisterReceiver statement, and how to reference the receiver. Can anyone help?

Main Activity:

```
CheckBox master_cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
master_cb.setText("Check All");
//HERE IS THE LIST VIEW WHICH I HAVE CREATED IN MY XML FILE.
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
//HERE I AM CREATING CUSTOM ADAPTER OBJECT.
my_custom_adapter adapter = new my_custom_adapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements);
lv.addHeaderView(master_cb);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
master_cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Intent my_intent = new Intent("master_check_change");
        my_intent.putExtra("check_value", isChecked);
        sendBroadcast(my_intent);
    }
});
```

my_customer_adapter:

```
public class my_custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context                     = null;
    ArrayList<String> elements                 = null;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked      = null;

    public my_custom_adapter(Context context, int type, ArrayList<String>  elements)
    {
        super(context, type, elements);
        this.elements =  elements;
        this.context = context;
        itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals("master_check_change")) {
                    boolean check_value = intent.getBooleanExtra("check_value", false);
                    set_checked(check_value);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("master_check_change"));
        set_checked(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move receiver variable:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
```

outside of constructor, then add myOnDestroy method to my_custom_adapter:

```
public myOnDestroy(){
    context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

now, call it inside your activity's onDestroy, ie:

```
((my_custom_adapter)(getListView().getAdapter())).myOnDestroy();
```

Comment: the getListView()  method couldn't be resolved in onDestroy (my activity extends ActionBarActivity). So I tried: "ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); ...((my_custom_adapter)(lv.getAdapter())).myOnDestroy();   ...but now I get java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter cannot be cast to ..my_custom_adapter ???